# Get list of Likes of a user using javascript FQL?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I'm working with Facebook's javascript API and I am trying out FQL using JavaScript.

Currently, I am able to login a user using the JavaScript plugin and get the user's name and profile photo.

I retrieve a user's name and profile photo by:

```
                function fqlQuery(){
                    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
                        var query = FB.Data.query('select name, hometown_location, sex, pic_square from user where uid={0}', response.id);
                            query.wait(function(rows) {
                                document.getElementById('name').innerHTML =
                                'Your name: ' + rows[0].name + "<br />" +
                                '<img src="' + rows[0].pic_square + '" alt="" />' + "<br />";
                            });
                        });
                }
```

May I know how do i get a full list of user's Likes using FQL?

I've tried doing `select likes from user where uid={0}`
but nothing happened.

May I know how do i go about doing it?

Best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't *think* this is possible, as you can see the indexable fields in the [`like`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/like/) table are `object_id` and `post_id` fields only and not the `user_id`

Answer (score 1):

You need to change this line

```
FB.api('/me', function(response) {
```

to

```
FB.api('/me/likes', function(response) {
```

Don't forget to add the permission "user_likes"

Comment: hello, i've tried that, but nothing came up. Thanks for suggesting that to me.

Answer (score 1):

```
FB.api('/me/likes', function(response) { 
  alert(response.error.message); <---- add this line to see what the issue is.
```